# undefined reference to `cJSON_Parse'

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, cjson

I am using Azure SDK. In the SDK I have included cJSON functionalities, I know I need to link cJSON.h to my code. But in azure makefile, I am finding it difficult. Do help in linking the cJSON header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could **add the json library to the makefile** to solve this problem.

Add

```
-ljson   \
```

to the linkflags in the makefile in the app directory and then was able to successfully compile.

Here is the similar [thread](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=763).

Comment: Only `-lcjson` worked for me for `libcjson-dev`. `-ljson` didn't work for me